# storing or appending contents (array) of a for loop to pass to another function - encapsulation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-services

I am working with a windows app form where I want a button to call a web service, MakeANote.
The web service requires information which is returned with the login along with a ticket.
the LogOn call has some input parameters, 1 ref (which i heard is both input and output), and some output parameters. BUT it also RETURNS an array of "Information". This array is put into my variable, pubinfo as follows:

```
Webservice.Information[] pubinfo = null; //initialize

pubinfo = myflo.LogOn(username, password, ref ticket, out settings, out users,out terms, out currentUser);
```

so the type is a custom type: Webservice.Information[]. Each Information element in the array has 3 properties: *string ID, string Name, and boolean ReversedRead.*

I was thinking that ---as this is filled in with the LogOn button and therefore encapsulated within the method calling it and ---- as i wanted to pass this info to the other web service, MakeANote, that I might do something like this:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < pubinfo.Length; i++)
            {
                objInfo = pubinfo[i];
                storePubInfo(objInfo);
                MessageBox.Show("PubInfo stored", "PubInfo");

            }
```

and store the pubinfo array in another function which the MakeANote function will have to call to collect it separately. This seems very messy to me, but I also want to keep things simple as I'm new to this all.

How would the storing function look like? Something as simple as this doesn't seem to work.

```
       public void storePubInfo()
       {
          return storePubInfo;
       }
```

I'm fine with appending it as well. Is that better? And is returning alright or do i actually have to have something like Webservice.Information storePubInfo(var)

When I click the button, my function to make a note is called with the argument of the ticket.. so the ticket gets passed without a problem. My question is the array that's being RETURNED with the logon, pubinfo.

---

I'm open for ideas if I'm trying to do this the wrong way, or there is a better way of doing this.
*Should I do something utterly different and perform the extraction in the buttonclick? Any good examples if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyClass
{
    List<Webservice.Information> _webServiceInformation = new List<Webservice.Information>()

    public void LogonAndStoreInfo()
    {
        Webservice.Information[] pubinfo = myflo.LogOn(username, password, ref ticket, out settings, out users,out terms, out currentUser);

        for (int i=0; i < pubInfo.Length; i++)
        {
            StorePubInfo(pubinfo);
        }

        Webservice.Information[] myPubInfo = GetPubInfo();
    }

    void StorePubInfo(Webservice.Information info)
    {
        _webServiceInformation.Add(info);
    }

    Webservice.Information[] GetPubInfo()
    {
        return _webServiceInformation.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tobsey for answering. I've implemented it, it didn't work initially until i put an index into the StorePubInfo(pubinfo[i]).. Then the code ran but had a server error. Which I believe is another problem entirely :( At least I'm a step farther, thanks!

Comment: Yep sorry about that. Of course you will need an index in the array. Good luck with the rest.